# How to have to bools that both cannot be true at the same time?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

This seems simple but for some reason it escapes me.
I have two bools and two methods that return bools. I want that if bool1 is set to true, bool2 will be set to false and vice versa. Here's how is looks in code.

```
bool b1, b2;
b1 = b1 ^ GUILayout.Button();
b2 = b2 ^ GUILayout.Button();
```

On the frame the button is click the method returns true. The way i'm using the XOR(^) makes the buttons toggle true and false.

Answer (score 0):

If the bools are always the opposite of one another, then why use two at all?

Say the bools we have in question are `ballBlue` and `ballGreen` (and in our world, we can only have one or the other - there are no red balls), for any given ball, only one can be true, and the other must be false.

In this instance, we can simply use `ballBlue`: if the value is true, then the ball must be blue. If it is not, then it is implied that the ball is instead green.

Comment: The methods i'm using return bools and I cannot change the methods because the methods must return bools. If I can compile the two bools into one your answer would work. Sadly I don't know how.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate more on the names of the functions and bools, so I can build up a better understanding of your specific situation?

Comment: I changed the summary of my question to show you how the methods worked.

Comment: It looks like what you might want are radio buttons: buttons where only 1 in a set can be selected at once. Your GUI framework may provide an elegant solution for this. If not, consider the other answer that has been proposed.

Comment: My GUIFramework doesn't have a solution to this. The other answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need boolean inversion

```
b1 =  MethodThatReturnsBool1();
b2 = (!b1)

b2 = MethodThatReturnsBool2();
b1 = (!b2)
```

Comment: then means I dont still get your question , you need both to be opposite depending on the output of the method right? example bool1 = method1 is true ,then bool2 must be false , if this is what you want, then my anwser is correct

Comment: Alright sorry, I actually had a different problem with your solution. If I use your solution both the bools cannot be false at the same time.